# ng-repeat in angularJs avoid duplicate values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have object like this

```
{
        {
          "assetId" : "560",
          "assetName" : "Testname",
          "message" : "hai",
          "timestamp" : 1452585984181
        },
         {
          "message" : "haii",
          "timestamp" : 1452585999592
        },
       {
          "assetId" : "560",
          "assetName" : "Testname",
          "message" : "heloo",
          "timestamp" : 1452586221604
        }
      }
```

show to this object i am using `ng-repeat`. My question is

I need to show all message using `ng-repat` comes under single `assetName`. but in this object two objects have same `assetName` and `assetId`. i need to show the messages both same objects but no need to repeatably show the `assetName` in top.

How can i only avoid the duplicate `assetName` and `assetId`.  I used

```
<div class="container" data-ng-repeat="data in dataList | unique:'assetId'">
```

But it's completely removing the object. I need the message from all objects.

is it possible.Please help
This is the out put i am expecting.:

[image]

Comment: Before assigning to the dataList scope parse the json and remvoe the repeated Id's.

Comment: Why are you using `unique` then? Not clear what expected results are

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<div class="container" data-ng-repeat="data in dataList | unique:'assetId'">
    <span>{{data.assetId}}</span>
    <div data-ng-repeat="data2 in dataList | filter:(data.assetId === undefined ? {assetId:'!'} : data.assetId)">
        <span>{{data2.message}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am only getting the assetId not getting other values in data2.

Comment: @Kichu I edited my answer. There was a copypasta from my tests. Check it now.

Comment: It's removing multiple assetId but the message is repeating 3 times. i don't know actual issue @Egan

Comment: The result should be `560 hai heloo haii`. You didn't tell us how do you want to show your data, so I made a simple example. You can add `Data:` and `Data2:` at the beginning of `span`s so you will see how it works.

Comment: This is chat application. so the message want to show only one time .Under the Unique assetId i will update the scree shot

Comment: How can i add or where i need to add data and data2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100461/discussion-between-kichu-and-egan-wolf).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own custom filter

```
yourApp.filter('customuniqueFilter', function() {
    return function( array, propertyThatMustBeUnique) {
        var newArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i++; i < array.length){
            if ( notYetInYourArray ){    // I was too lazy to think about a way to do it ;-) feel free to update my answer
                newArray.push(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
});
```

and then use it like this :

```
<div class="container" data-ng-repeat="data in dataList | customunique:'assetId'">
```

Comment: Thanks fo you reply. can you please help me to update the filter

Comment: This filter receives an `array` as parameter, and return the `newArray` that will be displayed. What you "just" need to do, is to check if the item already into `newArray` is, otherwise, push the item into `newArray`.